# History of sql calls in oracle with querytext and elapsed time

Tags: oracle, history

I need to know the following information in oracle

1. date and time of query run
2. query text
3. Total elapsed time for the query to execute

I checked with following ways

1. v$sql = It is logging only the last call's elapsed time
2. dba_hist_sqltext  - it is not logging my calls and it do not has elapsed time info.

Can you suggest some idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Much of what you want is in Oracle's Active Session History, which requires both Enterprise Edition as well as the separately-licensed Diagnostics Pack.